# Word for folding/tucking socks together?

Tags: single-word-requests

When folding shirts and things like that the word 'folding' makes sense. Is there a word for when placing socks on top of each other and then folding/inverting the top so they get stuck together?

Perhaps rolling is the proper word?

Here's an image for reference:
[image]

Comment: Sticking one inside the other, you mean?

Comment: Not precisely, that sounds like using one sock as a bag? You fold the top of one outward and envelop the top parts of both? Open to better ways of phrasing :)

Comment: Could you find us an image of this? I'm having trouble visualizing it.

Comment: @tchrist - Take a pair of socks.  Hold the tops together.  Reach your fingers into one top and "roll" the top down over the other top, so that the two socks become bound together.

Comment: (I would just call it "pairing socks".)

Comment: That image is completely rolled.  One can also choose to roll only the tops of the socks, so that the "feet" are dangling loose, but the tops are bound together.

Comment: I just call those “folded together” when one is inside the other, but since you wanted something other than that, I have no answer for you.

Comment: yeah @tchrist I don't know if there's another word. It just seems to be something which is not actually 'folded?' so I was curious if a word was out there for it.

Comment: What's wrong with folding?

Comment: @HotLicks I thought *pairing* too and was going to answer. But you got there first in comments.

Comment: @curiousdannii No problem - just was seeking a more precise word (a verb for this actual action) if one existed - doesn't look like there is one but I thought I'd check :)

Comment: In my family (I grew up in southeast Texas) we called the pictured item a "rolled-up pair of socks" and the action involved in producing a compact sock bundle of that sort was called "rolling them [the socks] up."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flype, a Scottish expression, is the verb you are looking for!

> As shown in The Dictionary of the Scots Language (www.dsl.ac.uk), *flype* was often used of clothing. For example, **socks can be flyped**, meaning folded inside out in pairs.  Examples of this appear in this 1904 quote from Erchie, *My Droll Friend* by Hugh Foulis (Neil Munro): “Efter this Erchie MacPherson’s gaun to flype his ain socks”, and this from Liz Lochhead’s *Dreaming Frankenstein* (1984): “So she turned his riddles inside out easily **like someone flyping pairs of socks**”.

Source: [Scots Language Centre](http://www.scotslanguage.co.uk/articles/view/id/4694)

Answer (score 5):

In Army Basic Combat Training and other arduous training schools in which wardrobe inspections were common and highly standardized, we had to roll our socks this way.  Actually, sometimes we were required to roll individual socks rather than a pair.  We had countless creative ways of describing the roll.  Depending on the viewing angle, the sock(s) smile or frown.  They have a "yoni" appearance, so all associated terms with "yoni," from traditional to medical-scientific as well as all vulgar terms were used to describe the type of sock(s) roll/fold. As far as verbs that describe the folding, rolling, tucking method required to get a sock or pair of socks into this configuration, I highly doubt one commonly accepted verb exists, but there likely are countless made-up words such as "fruck," a combination of the words "Fold," "Roll," and "tUCK."  I can imagine a drill instructor commanding recruits to fruck their socks according to standard operating procedure.

Comment: Tuck is what I had in mind.